# Datatable server side processing using java

Tags: java, jquery, json, datatable

I am using jquery datatable for my project. It's working well when i have less columns. But when it goes above 18 columns,it refuses to apply sorting and colvis functionalities. My current code is as below.

```
<table id="testTable" class="display nowrap stripe row-border order-column" cellspacing="0" align="center">
<%
    try {
      String a="";
      String acode = "N/A";
      int atp1, id4;
      query = "SELECT * FROM IETMS;";
      stmt = conn.createStatement();
      rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
      ResultSetMetaData rsmd=rs.getMetaData();
      int columns = rsmd.getColumnCount();
      if(rs.next()) {
%>
  <thead>
    <tr style="background-color: #3f91bd;color:white;">
      <% for (i=1; i<=columns-2; i++) {%>
        <th><%= rsmd.getColumnLabel(i) %></th>
      <%  } %>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr class="header">
      <% for (i=1; i<=columns-2; i++) {%>
      <th><%= rsmd.getColumnLabel(i) %></th>
      <%  }%>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
<%}%>
<tbody stye="border: 2px solid green;">
  <% while(rs.next()){ %>
    <tr class="clickable">
    <%
      for (i=1; i<=columns-2; i++) {
        if(rs.getObject(i) == null)
        {
          a = "N/A";
        } else
          a=""+rs.getObject(i);
    %>
    <td height="15"><%=a%></td>
    <% }%>
    </tr>
  <%}%>
</tbody>
<%
  } catch (Exception ex) {
      out.println(ex);
  }
%>
</table>
```

I'd like to move the implementation to a new JSP page that fetches data using JSON, but I'm not really all that familiar with JSON. I've looked at many examples, but it seems like JSON has a fixed schema, and I want to dynamically display whatever data is returned. Is there a way to do this with JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dynamically display JSON data, but it's not that easy and it's not necessarily tabular in nature. If you are certain that it follows a particular pattern -- say, an array of objects with no nested objects and each object has the same properties, then I suppose you could display it in a table format by iterating over the array and then iterating across each o the properties in the objects, displaying each property in a column:

Here's a piece of sample code using the Jackson API for instance -- it's not a JSP, but it's not hard to use roughly the same logic in JSP:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken;

public class JsonTable {
    JsonParser parser;

    public JsonTable( String filename ) {
        try {
            JsonFactory f = new JsonFactory();
            InputStream stream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream( filename );
            parser = f.createParser(stream);
        } catch ( IOException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String getTable() throws Exception {
        try {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            List<String> header = new ArrayList<>();
            if ( parser.nextToken() != JsonToken.START_ARRAY ) {
                throw new RuntimeException( "Expected an array of objects." );
            }
            while ( parser.nextToken().equals(JsonToken.START_OBJECT) ) {
                buildRow(header,builder);
            }
            if ( parser.currentToken() != JsonToken.END_ARRAY ) {
                throw new RuntimeException( "Expected end of JSON array, got: " + parser.currentToken() );
            }
            wrapRowsWithTable(header,builder);
            return builder.toString();
        } finally {
            parser.close();
        }
    }

    private void wrapRowsWithTable( List<String> columns, StringBuilder builder ) {
        StringBuilder header = new StringBuilder();
        header.append("<table><thead><tr>");
        for( String column : columns ) {
            header.append("<th>" + column + "</th>");
        }
        header.append("</tr></thead>");
        builder.insert(0,header.toString());
        builder.append("</table>");
    }

    private void buildRow( List<String> header, StringBuilder builder ) throws IOException {
        int index = 0;
        builder.append("<tr>");
        while(parser.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_OBJECT)
        switch( parser.currentToken() ) {
        case FIELD_NAME:
            if( header.size() > index ) {
                if( !header.get(index).equals( parser.getCurrentName() ) ) {
                    throw new RuntimeException( "Expected field: " + header.get(index) + ", found: " + parser.getCurrentName() );
                }
            } else {
                header.add(parser.getCurrentName());
            }
            index++;
            break;
        case VALUE_NULL:
        case VALUE_TRUE:
        case VALUE_FALSE:
        case VALUE_NUMBER_INT:
        case VALUE_NUMBER_FLOAT:
        case VALUE_STRING:
            builder.append("<td>" + parser.getText() + "</td>");
            break;
        case VALUE_EMBEDDED_OBJECT:
            throw new RuntimeException( "Expecting an array of objects with no nested objects." );
        default:
            throw new RuntimeException( "Unexpected token: " + parser.currentToken() );
        }
    }
}
```

This expects the fields to follow the same order, which might not work for every scenario -- you could enhance it to allow fields to appear in any order and/or be optional.

If the data is a JSON object tree or some other kind of pattern, it's not going to be easy to represent that as a table.

Comment: Thank you for response Mr.Geoffrey. I have checked many json examples. But all i got are supports only when the person knows the columns to  fetched. It would be great if you have any sample code suitable for above situation?